# Take all elements of .Split (' ') and take last OR exclude last item

Tags: c#, linq

I have an inconsistend address field which I am reading from excel. I need to split this field and enter those 2 values into two list properties.

the content could be something like this

> At the gates 42

I need to split the number from the rest and add "At the gates" to the property "Street" and "42" to the property "number"

I have solved the problem with taking the number with this:

```
Number = Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[j + 3, i + 2].Value).Split(' ').LastOrDefault()
```

How can I split this string with Linq and just exclude the last number to get the street?

Kind regards

Comment: you really need it to be in linq?

Comment: is last value is always numeric???

Comment: Yes, you mention the data is "inconsistent"...how so?  I.e. what other ways does this address data exist?

Comment: Linq would be prefferable - a one line solution in a perfect world ;)
Inconsistent in the way, that there are different numbers of words in it and there may be a digit, maybe not. The number can also be '130 A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex so you can also have it flexible to your needs.

Here's a sample:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<words>[A-Za-z ]+)(?<digits>[0-9]+)");

        string input = "At the gates 42";

        var match = regex.Match(input);
        var a = match.Groups["words"].Value; //At the gates 
        var b = match.Groups["digits"].Value; //42
    }
```

Comment: Probably better would be Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<words>[^0-9]+)(?<digits>[0-9]+)");

Comment: yep. that could work. Im just assuming that the address will just contain alphanumeric characters.

Comment: The address also contains non-alphanumeric characters, but I've taken your code and modified it slightly to represent that fact. Everyting is put in a helper method and it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the string is a bit too much here. You just need to find the last occurence of " " and split at this position:

```
var address = "At the gates 42";
var idx = address.LastIndexOf(' ');
var street = address.Substring(0, idx);
var number = address.Substring(idx + 1);
```

Also consider using regular expressions if you need more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
String[] sa = Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[j + 3, i + 2].Value).Split(' ');
Int32 number = Convert.ToInt32(sa[sa.Length - 1]);
String street = String.Join(" ", sa.Take(sa.Length - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use LastIndexOf for this (if you can safely assume that your house numbers don't have spaces in):

```
var original = Convert.ToString(ws.Cells[j + 3, i + 2].Value).Split().LastOrDefault()
var street = original.Substring(1, original.LastIndexOf(' '))
var number = original.Substring(original.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1)
```

Note that it might be easier to get Excel to do the work for you though, you could use a formula in your sheet to perform the same function, so...

This gives you the street name (assuming your original value is in cell A1, just replace all occurrences of A1 otherwise):

```
=MID(A1,1,LOOKUP(9.9999999999E+307,FIND(" ",A1,ROW($1:$1024)))-1)
```

and this gives you the number:

```
=MID(A1,LOOKUP(9.9999999999E+307,FIND(" ",A1,ROW($1:$1024)))+1,LEN(A1))
```